# Instance method is not replaced in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I have the following Python code:

```
>>> class My:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "My object"
    def __str__(self):
        return "My object"


>>> my = My()
>>> my.__repr__ = lambda: "I just changed repr"
>>> my.__repr__
<function <lambda> at 0x00000000033A91E0>
>>> repr(my)
'My object'
```

I can't understand why `repr(my)` doesn't return the new value of `__repr__`. I checked other functions and all of them worked the same way. It seems that Python checks the class first instead of checking whether the instance does have the required method.

Is it possible to override `__repr__` in the instance level, without having to create a new class?

Comment: This works as expected for me (Python 2.7)

Comment: In new style classes the special methods are looked up in class not instance.

Comment: I guess a workaround would be to define __repr__ to call f and change f for the instance.